# How to add decimal separators to numbers in certain columns - Bash

Tags: bash, awk, vim

I have a .txt file and I need to add commas as decimal separators to improve the readability. The numbers only exist in certain columns and I couldn't find a way to do that. The columns are separated by semicolons and can contain any character. 
The numbers are in the third and fourth columns.

This

```
BitstreamCyberCJK;Freeware;30275;28686;v2.0 beta (1998-03-17);Cyberbit.ttf (12.4 MB);Bitstream CyberCJK;Medium (Normal), Book, Roman;TTF;Cove

Y.OzFontN;Freeware;21957;57621;v13.00 sfnt rev 5 Pen-Ji (2010-08-24);YOzRN.TTC (13.5 MB);YOzFontN;Regular;TTC;Any
```

should turn into this:

```
BitstreamCyberCJK;Freeware;30,275;28,686;v2.0 beta (1998-03-17);Cyberbit.ttf (12.4 MB);Bitstream CyberCJK;Medium (Normal), Book, Roman;TTF;Cove

Y.OzFontN;Freeware;21,957;57,621;v13.00 sfnt rev 5 Pen-Ji (2010-08-24);YOzRN.TTC (13.5 MB);YOzFontN;Regular;TTC;Any
```

I thought about using an if statement in awk to check if the length of those columns are bigger than 3, but then I couldn't find a way to put the commas in between every three digits.

I tried my best and came up with this but interestingly the system I am using doesn't run gawk and I don't know the differences between gawk and awk to correct my code.

```
gawk '  BEGIN {OFS=FS=";"} {for(i=1;i<NF;i++) {if($i ~ /^[0-9]+$/) $i = sprintf("%'\''d", $i)}} 1'
```

Comment: The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: I wrote this but the problem is I am not familiar with the differences of gawk and awk and the system I am trying to upload does not run gawk.  gawk '  BEGIN {OFS=FS=";"} {for(i=1;i<NF;i++) {if($i ~ /^[0-9]+$/) $i = sprintf("%'\''d", $i)}} 1'

Comment: Do you always want three decimal places?

Comment: Yes, i think i should change the last three digits in those columns with themselves preceded by a comma. But can't find a way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it :

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 awk -F';'  'BEGIN{ OFS=";" }{ $4=sprintf("%'"'"'d", $4); $3=sprintf("%'"'"'d", $3) ; print $0}' file.txt
```

Hope its useful.

Comment: Would that work with a `$''`-style string, so single quotes in format specifiers could be just `\'`? I can never remember if that is specific to some particular shell or a POSIX thing.

Comment: `'"'"'` is identical in function to `'\''` - they both escape from the awk script to let the shell provide a `'` that then becomes part of the awk script before awk interprets it. You can get the same functionality using the octal escape sequence `\047` for the `'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

this will convert all numbers

```
$ awk -F';' 'function pp(x) {tt=int(x/1000); 
                             return tt?(pp(tt)","(x%1000)):x}
              BEGIN {OFS=FS} 
                    {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i+0==$i) $i=pp($i)}1' file


BitstreamCyberCJK
BitstreamCyberCJK;Freeware;30,275;28,686;v2.0 beta (1998-03-17);Cyberbit.ttf (12.4 MB);Bitstream CyberCJK;Medium (Normal), Book, Roman;TTF;Cove


Y.OzFontN
Y.OzFontN;Freeware;21,957;57,621;v13.00 sfnt rev 5 Pen-Ji (2010-08-24);YOzRN.TTC (13.5 MB);YOzFontN;Regular;TTC;Any
```

should work for larger numbers as well...

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r ':a; s/;([0-9]+)([0-9]{3})(([,][0-9]*)*)($|[;])/;\1,\2\3\5/g; ta' textfile
```

Explanation:
`sed -r` : Avoid backslashes
`:a;` : label for repeating the replacement
`;([0-9]+)` : At least one number before the next three
`([0-9]{3})` : three digits
`(([,][0-9]{3})*)` : optional sets of a comma with 3 digits
`($|[;])` : End-of-line or End-of-field
`/;\1,\2\3\5/g;` : replace by the dound data with additional comma
`ta` : when replacement worked go back to label a and repeat

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're asking because `sprintf("%'...` doesn't work with your awk on your UNIX box, one way would be to left-pad each number with 0s to make it a multiple of 3 digits long, then put a comma in front of every 3 digits, then remove the leading 0s and commas:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=";"} {for (i=3; i<=4; i++) {$i=sprintf("%099d",$i); gsub(/.../,",&",$i); sub(/^(,0+)+/,"",$i)} } 1' file
BitstreamCyberCJK;Freeware;30,275;28,686;v2.0 beta (1998-03-17);Cyberbit.ttf (12.4 MB);Bitstream CyberCJK;Medium (Normal), Book, Roman;TTF;Cove
Y.OzFontN;Freeware;21,957;57,621;v13.00 sfnt rev 5 Pen-Ji (2010-08-24);YOzRN.TTC (13.5 MB);YOzFontN;Regular;TTC;Any
```

The above would work as long as your input numbers are no longer than 99 digits (e.g. are smaller than `1` followed by 99 zeros). If you'd rather not hard-code a limit then with a little more code you could just pad the fields with zeros to the nearest multiple of 3 digits long:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=";"} {for (i=3; i<=4; i++) {$i=sprintf("%0*d",int((length($i)+2)/3)*3,$i); gsub(/.../,",&",$i); sub(/^(,0+)+/,"",$i)} } 1' file
BitstreamCyberCJK;Freeware;30,275;28,686;v2.0 beta (1998-03-17);Cyberbit.ttf (12.4 MB);Bitstream CyberCJK;Medium (Normal), Book, Roman;TTF;Cove
Y.OzFontN;Freeware;21,957;57,621;v13.00 sfnt rev 5 Pen-Ji (2010-08-24);YOzRN.TTC (13.5 MB);YOzFontN;Regular;TTC;Any
```

There's no looping involved in the formatting so it should be efficient even for large numbers.